# Laravel 8 save integer into null DB column - save vs update

Tags: laravel-8

I'm having an interesting issue where Laravel's `save()` does not replace `null` values in database, while the `update()` does. I also tested by manually changing `null` to `1` and afterwards the `save()` started updating the column. I am using `save()` throughout the project and would prefer that it stays that way or that at least I understand the problem before I go changing the code.

Migration (all codes will be partial extracts for brewity):

```
$table->foreignId('checklist_id')->nullable()->constrained('checklists')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
$table->foreignId('action_id')->nullable()->constrained('actions')->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Model (added the checklist_id and action_id for testing, otherwise they are not here):

```
// test
protected $fillable = [
    'checklist_id',
    'action_id',
];

protected $casts = [
    'checklist_id' => 'integer',
    'action_id' => 'integer',
];

// actual
protected $fillable = [
];

protected $casts = [
];
```

Controller:

```
public function update(UpdateWorkOrderRequest $request, WorkOrder $workOrder)
{
        $response = $workOrder->save($request->all());
}
```

Form submission (from Chrome):

```
------WebKitFormBoundary73Z4wzsmsGcgOOAM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="checklist_id"

1
------WebKitFormBoundary73Z4wzsmsGcgOOAM
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action_id"

1
```

dd($request->all()):

```
array:2 [▼
  "checklist_id" => "1"
  "action_id" => "1"
]
```

The fields `checklist_id` and `action_id` are `null` after using `save()`, but they do get updated using `update()`. It's also working if I do this:

```
$workOrder->checklist_id = $request->checklist_id;
$workOrder->action_id = $request->action_id;
$workOrder->save();
```

I opted for `save()` to write less code instead of above example and because from docs I presume I can use `save()` when assigning data from `$request`, like here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates

Comment: Where in the docs does it state that you can use an assoc array inside the `model->save()` function? To use an assoc array for assignment use: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#mass-assignment  ( `$workOrder->fill($request->all())->save();` ) (untested). PS: I'd discourage directly assigning values like this. If someone adds other values to the request attributes they could override values unintentionally. At the very least make sure to filter the list before mass assigning

Comment: I always assumed that the values are filtered by `$fillable` array and nothing else gets through. I had issues in the past where I forgot to add attributes to `$fillable` and those were not saved. EDIT: even the docs say that.

Comment: p.s.: It works this way for all other fields, just the nullable are problematic where initial state is `null`.

Comment: My bad - those indeed get filtered. Nice to see you tested it though.

Comment: No problem ;) Dealt with rouge users and injections of any kind already.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243882/discussion-between-kerwin-sneijders-and-kristjan-o).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you're trying to use `model->save(attributes)`.

The save function does not provide any parameters for this. ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_save)).

---

You have two options, either use the `model->update` function ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_update)):

```php
$workOrder->update($request->all());
```

Or use the `model->fill` ([docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill)) function in combination with `model->save` like so:

```php
$workOrder->fill($request->all())->save();
```